# Adding '£' sign to ggplot axis, when font is defined.

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a '£' sign to the below ggplot y axis label. However, when I run the code the £ sign is blank i.e. "Mean cost ( )", instead of "Mean cost (£)". There are no warnings.

I imagine it's because I'm calling a particular font (GoodDog Plain, via extrafont package), because when I remove all themes, the £ sign appears. However, as I need to use this font, does anyone know of a way around this?

```
ggplot(FTAt, aes(x=Year, y=FTA_cost, col=Country, group=Country)) + 
  geom_line(size=1)+
  ylab("Mean cost (£)") +
  xlab("Year")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red2", "royalblue4","forestgreen"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family="GoodDog Plain"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(family="GoodDog Plain"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(family="GoodDog Plain"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(family="GoodDog Plain"),
    legend.title = element_text(family="GoodDog Plain"),
    legend.text = element_text(family="GoodDog Plain"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow K.McM. I had similar problems using the € symbol lately. What solved my problems was exchanging € by \u20AC in my labels-strings. According to this page: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A3/index.htm the unicode for the pound should be \u00A3.

Comment: By the looks of it, your font simply doesn't contain the pound sign: https://www.1001fonts.com/gooddog-plain-font.html#character-map

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,mpg)) + 
  geom_point()+
  ylab("Mean cost (£)") +
  xlab("Year")
```

[image]
My system

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 Service Pack 1
```

and

```
ggplot2_3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "£"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The font you are using does not contain a £, if you cannot use a different font, then it would be best to use:

```
+ylab("Mean cost (GBP)")
```

or since the font's opening curly bracket looks reasonably like a pound symbol:

```
 +ylab("Mean cost ({)")
```

If you are still not happy, you could try as a not transferable solution to superimpose a dash "-" under an "F":

```
 +ylab("Mean cost (F)")
...

text('-',x,y,cex=size,family="GoodDog Plain",xpd=NA,srt=90)
```

You will need to change the values of x, y and size manually until it is in the right place and looks good.